# launch a function from angular controller with Parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I need to launch a function that needs parameters from the json I get, 
the request is:

```
app.controller('getDataCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicLoading) {

$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://someurl/GetPlaylist",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).then(function mySucces(response) {

    $scope.allTracks = response.data;
    $scope.recentTracks = response.data.Tracks;
//now i want to luanch the function below that written in a different js file
//and pass parameters
        **startCration(recentTracks[0].Song, recentTracks[0].Artist);**

}, function myError(response) {
    $scope.allTracks = response.statusText;
});
});
```

and here's the function I need to launch

```
function startCration(song, artist) {

    MusicControls.create({
        track: song,        
        artist: artist,                           
    }, onCreateSuccess, onCreateError);
```

but I can't seem to call the function after the success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you assigned all your tracks to `$scope.recentTracks`, you should refer to `$scope.recentTracks` instead of only `recentTracks`.

```
startCration(recentTracks[0].Song, recentTracks[0].Artist);
```

should be

```
startCration($scope.recentTracks[0].Song, $scope.recentTracks[0].Artist);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can basically broadcast an event on success. Here's the updated code:

```
app.controller('getDataCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicLoading,$rootScope) {

$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://someurl/GetPlaylist",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).then(function mySucces(response) {

    $scope.allTracks = response.data;
    $scope.recentTracks = response.data.Tracks;
//now i want to luanch the function below that written in a different js file
//and pass parameters
 $rootScope.$broadcast('response-recieved', { response: response.data });

}, function myError(response) {
    $scope.allTracks = response.statusText;
});
});
```

Now , in your different js file you can listen to the above event as follows:

```
$scope.$on('response-recieved', function(event, args) {

    var res= args.response.Tracks;
    // do what you want to do
    startCration(res[0].Song, res[0].Artist); // call to your function.
});
```